# Java Script Redirect Not Working With IFrame, Works without IFrame

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

I am using a PHP form to collect information. I want it to redirect to a page on the same domain when the submit button is pushed. It works fine if you go to the php form, but not the iframed php form. The code is below.

```
define( 'PHPFMG_REDIRECT', 'http://propertytaxdfw.com/thank-you-sign-up.html' );
function phpfmg_thankyou(){
// move the redirect to phpfmg_thankyou() to get around the redirection within an iframe problem
        /*
        $redirect = PHPFMG_REDIRECT;
        if( strlen(trim($redirect)) ):
            header( "Location: $redirect" );
            exit;
        endif;
        */
    phpfmg_redirect_js();
?>

<!-- [Your confirmation message goes here] -->
    <br>

    <b>It Worked!</b>
    <br><br>

<?php

} // end of function phpfmg_thankyou()
```

I think that is where the problem is. I can provide additional code if needed. I appreciate your help in advance. I have read a lot of things on here trying to find an answer, but I feel like I am stuck.

The form: http://propertytaxdfw.com/SignUpFormFiles/form.php
Page where iframed: http://propertytaxdfw.com/sign-up.html

```
function phpfmg_redirect_js(){
    if( defined('PHPFMG_REDIRECT') && '' != PHPFMG_REDIRECT ){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
            function phpfmg_redirect(){
                var redirect = '" . addslashes(PHPFMG_REDIRECT) . "';
                try{
                    if( parent ) parent.location.href = redirect;
                }catch(e){
                    location.href = redirect;
                };
            }

            phpfmg_redirect();
        </script>";
    };
```

Comment: You have to change the question's title. It is not PHP redirect i.e using `header()`  function. It is Javascript redirect.

Comment: Changed. Sorry, not a programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 6 error:**

The 2nd and 3rd brackets must be removed.

```
   this.submitOK = function(){
  window.top.location.href = redirect; 
}
    }


}
```

### Update 6

Delete

```
    if( redirect == '' ){
        showThankYouMessage();
        return;
    };

try{
    if( parent ) {alert('parent');parent.location.href = redirect;}

}catch(e){  alert('frame');
    location.href = redirect;
};
```

And replace with this one line: `window.top.location.href = redirect;`.

```
this.submitOK = function(){
  window.top.location.href = redirect; 
}
```

### Update 5

Remove previous alert and add two others a little further down, parent and frame.

```
this.submitOK = function(){
    if( redirect == '' ){
        showThankYouMessage();
        return;
    };

try{
    if( parent ) {alert('parent');parent.location.href = redirect;}

}catch(e){  alert('frame');
    location.href = redirect;
};
```

}

### Update 4

At form.lib.php line 2484 (may be different due to previous edits)

Add the line `alert('OK');`

Then when the form is submitted, a message box 'OK' should pop up.

```
   this.submitOK = function(){
   alert('OK');

        if( redirect == '' ){
            showThankYouMessage();
            return;
        };

        try{
            if( parent ) parent.location.href = redirect;
        }catch(e){
            location.href = redirect;
        };
    }
```

**end of update 4**

---

### Update 3

**In form.lib.php on Line 11**

```
define( 'PHPFMG_REDIRECT', '' );
```

Must be:

```
define( 'PHPFMG_REDIRECT', 'http://propertytaxdfw.com/thank-you-sign-up.html' );
```

**end of update 3**

### Update 2

If you can find where this code is added.

```
function PHPFMG( formID ){
    var frmID = formID;
    var exts = {
        'upload_control' : '',
        'harmful_exts'  : '.php, .html, .css, .js, .exe, .com, .bat, .vb, .vbs, scr, .inf, .reg, .lnk, .pif, .ade, .adp, .app, .bas, .chm, .cmd, .cpl, .crt, .csh, .fxp, .hlp, .hta, .ins, .isp, .jse, .ksh, .Lnk, .mda, .mdb, .mde, .mdt, .mdw, .mdz, .msc, .msi, .msp, .mst, .ops, .pcd, .prf, .prg, .pst, .scf, .scr, .sct, .shb, .shs, .url, .vbe, .wsc, .wsf, .wsh',
        'harmful_errmsg': "File is potential harmful. Upload is not allowed.",
        'allow_exts'  : '.jpg, .gif, .png, .bmp',
        'allow_errmsg': "Upload is not allowed. Please check your file type."
    };
    var redirect = "http://propertytaxdfw.com/thank-you-sign-up.html";
```

Move `var redirect = "http://propertytaxdfw.com/thank-you-sign-up.html";`

to above the function

```
var redirect = "http://propertytaxdfw.com/thank-you-sign-up.html";
function PHPFMG( formID ){
    var frmID = formID;
    ...
```

Or replace `redirect` with the actual URL in theis function:
Delete `if( redirect == '' ){`

```
this.submitOK = function(){
        if( redirect == '' ){
            showThankYouMessage();
            return;
        };

        try{
            if( parent ) parent.location.href = redirect;
        }catch(e){
            location.href = redirect;
        };
    }
```

Change to:

```
this.submitOK = function(){
        try{
            if( parent ) parent.location.href = 'http://propertytaxdfw.com/thank-you-sign-up.html';
        }catch(e){
            location.href = redirect;
        };
    }
```

**end of update 2**

---

I am not a big fan of the redirect.

Most times when a redirect is used a simple `include()` or `readfile()`.

The problem with a redirect is it requires the Browser to do and additional (and unnecessary) HTTP request.

Why do a redirect when it is not necessary?

In your case it will probably work where a redirect will not.

Either of these should work fine.

```
if( strlen(trim($redirect))){
  readfile($redirect);
  exit;
}
if( strlen(trim($redirect))){
  include($redirect);
  exit;
}
if( strlen(trim($redirect))){
  echo file_get_contents($redirect);
  exit;
}
```

### UPDATE 1

The required redirect JS is not in the iFrame: https://propertytaxdfw.com/SignUpFormFiles/form.php.

Either function phpfmg_redirect_js() is not being executed in the PHP or  `defined('PHPFMG_REDIRECT')` is not defined, or `PHPFMG_REDIRECT` is an empty string`('' != PHPFMG_REDIRECT)`.

Two things to try:
Add this to the PHP:

```
define("PHPFMG_REDIRECT", "http://propertytaxdfw.com/thank-you-sign-up.html");
```

Or add this to the PHP:

```
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
    function phpfmg_redirect(){
      var redirect = '" . addslashes(PHPFMG_REDIRECT) . "';
      try{
      if( parent ) parent.location.href = redirect;
      }catch(e){
        location.href = redirect;
      };
    }
    phpfmg_redirect();
</script>";
```

When the page is created by the PHP if the above JS is found withing the existing
 `<script type='text/javascript'> </script>`
 then change the code to:

```
    echo "\nfunction phpfmg_redirect(){
      var redirect = '" . addslashes(PHPFMG_REDIRECT) . "';
      try{
      if( parent ) parent.location.href = redirect;
      }catch(e){
        location.href = redirect;
      };
    }
    phpfmg_redirect();\n";
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74826/discussion-on-answer-by-misunderstood-java-script-redirect-not-working-with-ifra).